# Combinatorial Species of a Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorial-species

A combinatorial species has an associated exponential generating function, which counts the number of occurrences of labelled objects of that species, of a given size.

Table 1 on p409 of "Combinatorial Species and Tree-Like Structures" by Bergeron, Labelle, and Leroux gives a 'dictionary' relating species and generating functions (GF). For example, the species of Sets has GF $e^x$, the species of linear orders has GF $1/1-x$.

Species can be recursively constructed by composing elementary species in a variety of ways (e.g. Cartesian product, substitution etc).

**Q**. Given a GF $F(x)$, is there a *computationally-efficient* means of determining a corresponding species?

My understanding is that such determination may not be unique (for example, the species of permutations and of linear orders have the same GF).

EDIT (in response to @user43208's comment): The inverse mapping should ideally capture some notion of 'parsimony' w.r.t. the species it yields. For example, if the species is actually $1/(1 - e^x)$ (i.e. a composition of elementary species), this would ideally be the result given. This can be achieved *inefficiently* by a process of 'inverse dictionary substitution', but the question is concerned with the existence of a computationally-superior method.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question, because (assuming that the $a_n$ of $\sum_n \frac{a_n x^n}{n!}$ are natural numbers), just define a species $A$ by $A[n] = \{1, \ldots, a_n\}$ and letting the symmetric group $S_n$ act trivially on $A[n]$.

Comment: I don't understand what you have in mind by saying "parsimony". Which would be more "ideal": the species for permutations or the species for linear orders? Both are obviously important. (I confess that I don't know what "inverse dictionary substitution" is.) To try to sharpen the question: consider a monomial egf, whose nonzero Taylor coefficient $a_n$ is the cardinality of a set on which $S_n$ can act in many different ways. What is the criterion for deciding which action to pick?

Comment: @user43208 With all due caveats for informality of the following:
Bergeron et al's book gives a 'forward dictionary' collection of rules for composing GFs in terms of the composition of species. Efficiency aside, one can conceive of inverting that process, effectively applying (the inverse of) any rule with a RHS that matches against (a sub-part of) the GF. One then conceptually ends up with a set of candidates. Parsimony means the kind of preference heuristic that a human mathematician might apply, e.g.  prefer a description in terms of a small number of concise elementary compositions.

Comment: Perhaps I should stand aside and let someone else have a crack at your question, but could you say what you think the answer should be between permutations and linear orders? I'm also puzzled by the tension between countably many descriptions and uncountably many egfs, let alone species. Anyway, I hope my questions are taken more in a spirit of stimulating further thought.

Comment: @user43208 Given the isomorphism, there's no apriori reason to distinguish between permutations and linear orders: hence, there would be no intrinsic preference between them in the list of candidate species that inverse dictionary substitution would return.

Comment: Isomorphism? An isomorphism between the species of linear orders and the species of permutations? There isn't any. If you didn't mean that, then what did you mean? (The fact these aren't isomorphic is a very important point. It's the difference between $S_n$ acting on its underlying set by left multiplication, versus $S_n$ acting by conjugation.)

Comment: @user43208 Apologies for such loose language: isomorphic w.r.t. counting.

Comment: If you say there is no basis for distinguishing between species if they yield the same cardinalities (i.e., the same egf), then I really have no idea what you are asking about in the first place. We can try to talk about this in chat if you want.

Comment: @user43208 I'm saying 'no reason for distinguishing' at the level of "linOrder versus perm as *leaves in a hierarchical species structure*" - the actual overall structure is important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144901/discussion-between-user43208-and-nietzscheanai).